# how to solve "'Resource' object has no attribute 'service' " in python , google api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

i was trying to make a project using google api. in that project i give a string and the python script is supposed to change/modify that a cell in google sheet and change the value of the cell that string. But the problem is that there is a error-

`request = sheet.service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'service'` 
what should i do ?

here is the code -

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from google.oauth2 import service_account

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'python-sheets-keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
       SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.

# The ID of the spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '14uNIk1Q_jNKRL-yuz5Fssu3iVsQzmYf6wHXZDnjWkW0'


service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,                           range="test!A1:B10").execute()
values = result.get('values', [])

value_for_write = [("present")]

request = sheet.service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                           range="Sheet2!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":value_for_write}).execute()

print(values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about modifying as follows?

#### From:

```
value_for_write = [("present")]

request = sheet.service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                           range="Sheet2!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":value_for_write}).execute()
```

#### To:

```
value_for_write = [["present"]]
request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Sheet2!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":value_for_write}).execute()
```

- In your script, `sheet = service.spreadsheets()` is used. So I used it.
- `value_for_write` of `{"values":value_for_write}` for `sheet.values().update` is required to be 2 dimensional array.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: @Scarlett Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.